# Атоматический запуск 1С [8.2]

Tags: 1с

Доброго всем [утра:дня:вечера:ночи].
Вопрос примитивный, но я с 1С не работаю уже с тех времён, когда по земле бегали динозавры.
Итак вопрос:
Я сделал ярлычок:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\1cv82\common\1cestart.exe" ENTERPRISE /S"server_1c" /N"user" /P"pass"

И оно не работает. Т.е. выводит окно выбора баз. Входит без предложения ввода имени и пароля.
Но ведь хотелось бы от автоматизации полной реализации.
Вот там где у файловых баз путь показывает, у серверной показывает это:

> Srvr="server_1c";Ref="bd_name";

Куда впихнуть это? И как состряпать правильный lnk?
P.S. Имена бд, юзеров и пассы - в примере вымышленные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Неужели не гуглится?

```
"[путь к файлу 1cv8.exe]" enterprise /S[сервер_1с]\[имя_базы] /N [пользователь] /P [пароль]
```

Например

```
"C:\Program Files\1cv82\8.2.13.219\bin\1cv8.exe" enterprise /S"server___1c\bd_name" /N"user" /P"pass"
```

Answer (score 0):

**1C - Кривая как и всегда !!!

Оказывается:**
—————————————————————————————————————————————
Файл: 1cestart.exe

Полный путь: C:\Program Files\1cv82\common\1cestart.exe

Назначение: Универсальный стартер системы 1С. Предполагается, что он помогает определить версию 1С, под которую написана запускаемая база, после чего запускает конфигуратор, толстый или тонкий клиент конкретной версии 1С. На деле, вопреки документации и опциям, умеет запускать только конфигуратор и тонкий клиент. Толстый клиент через  1cestart.exe запустить невозможно! Данная ошибка актуальна как минимум для версии 8.2.15.301, хотя в сети встречается информация, что ошибка была исправлениа в 8.2.14.x.
—————————————————————————————————————————————
Вот оно что!
И не будет работать!
Расходимся, кина не будет.
**Дружно юзаем ..\bin\1cv8.exe**